# Multiple django storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have a django project in which all my static and media files are stored on s3. The storage for the same is the default storage. I created another storage for my private files.

```
protected_storage = S3BotoStorage(
    acl='private',
    bucket=settings.IMPORT_SHEETS_BUCKET,
    querystring_auth=True,
    querystring_expire=60,
)
```

In one of my models there is a file field.

```
import_sheet = models.FileField(storage=protected_storage)
```

When I upload a file to this field, it is uploaded to the required bucket. However when i try to access it from django admin, I get a url of the default storage bucket. Thoughts?